# how would i display uinput in this h1 tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make the `uinput` appear in the `h1`-tag after the word `Hello`. It should display the users name that they added in a previous page.

```
<body>
    <div class="Header_2">
        <div class="Head-Text-Box">
            <script>
                var userinput = localStorage.getItem("uinput");
            </script>
            <h1>Hello uinput <br> please choose from the options below</h1>
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get initial innerHTML of heading tag and replace innerHTML with your variable value:

```html
<div class="Header_2">
        <div class="Head-Text-Box">
            <h1>Hello {uinput} <br> please choose from the options below.</h1>
            <script>
                var userinput = "Sixpathsage6";//localStorage.getItem("uinput");
                var h = document.querySelector("h1");
                h.innerHTML = h.innerHTML.replace("{uinput}",userinput);
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Use Regular expression to replace multiple `{uinput}`:

```
h.innerHTML.replace(/\{uinput\}/g, userinput);
```